# Sonarqube pull request decoration with Bitbucket

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, pull-request, sonarqube-ops

so I have a trial license for SonarQube Developer Edition

after SonarQube installation, configured PR decoration for Bitbucket Server, using the Pull Request Analysis documentation

Now what steps do I do to get it to scan the bitbucket project for a pull request? Where would I place the paramters and such as I am lost with this at the moment/

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide some more details about your project: namely what tool you're using to build it (Maven, Gradle, MsBuild etc)

Comment: building it with Maven, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sonarqube is not scanning your code nor bitbucket is doing that. Most likely this is done by your CI-Tool like jenkins,bamboo etc. Your build tool will then upload this to your sonarqube instance, which will allow you to revisit those code changes and see issues and coverage etc. and than, bitbucket can fetch those data and display it.

That means you have to configure more than just two tools. You need to tell sonarqube when you are doing the analyses, what your branch is, or what your pullrequest is, so it can reference that. As it is described in the [Documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/)

If you do not want to trigger a build on each commit, you can use a plugin like pull request notifier, but more about it in this answer [Old Way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428486/sonarqube-and-bitbucket-integration-on-pull-request/46429735#46429735)