# Connect SonarQube with Bitbucket repo

Tags: sonarqube, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I've created a new SonarCube project and want to connect it to a repository in BitBucket. I know there is a Sonar plug-in for BitBucket to view stats inside Bitbucket. However, I want to see these stats inside SonarQube. 
Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sonarqube and bitbucket alone, will not generate any data, as long as you do not have some kind of build tool to generate those data. You need a Sonarqube Scanner, which scans your codebase and commits it to sonarqube first. i recommend you to read those "Answers"

[Difference between SonarQube server and Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588950/3708208)

> first the Sonarqube-server, which is holding the configuration of
>   projects, quality gates and quality profiles (aka rulesets). The
>   purpose of the server is the displaying part and managing part. It
>   will show you all your issues, and it will allow you to manage it. BUT
>   it will not analyse your source code.
>
> second the scanner. This is the part which is analyzing your source
>   code. It will ask the server for the quality profile and its rules. It
>   will go through your configured files and try to look for those issues
>   and it will generate a report, which will be commited to the
>   sonarqube-server to be evaluated and displayed

and [Integrate Sonarqube and bitbucket (old version, before the plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428486/sonarqube-and-bitbucket-integration-on-pull-request/46429735#46429735) or the [sonarqube documentation for the new plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/)